# Loop executing a command using maximum arguments as possible

Tags: arrays, shell, loops, command-line-arguments

I have a program that can handle ~256 files at the same time (edit: limit given by command line arguments number); and I have to execute it on many files I have (more than 100k).

To do this, for now, I'm using a simple loop, calling my program once for each file, one by one.

```
FILESLIST="$(find /folder/where/the/files/are/ -name '*.xml' 2>/dev/null)"
FILESTAB=($FILESLIST)

for f in "${FILESTAB[@]}"
do
    ./myProgram $f || break
done
```

But in order to increase the speed of my process, I need to use my program with more than single file each time like following:

```
./myProgram path/to/file1.xml path/to/file2.xml ...
```

I think about something like following, but I can't find a good idea to make this (see comments):

```
FILESLIST="$(find /folder/where/the/files/are/ -name '*.xml' 2>/dev/null)"
FILESTAB=($FILESLIST)

while [ ${#FILESTAB[@]} -gt 256 ]
do
    ListOf256FilesNames=$FILETAB[0:256]        # << My problem is to do this
    FILETAB=$FILETAB[256:end] # shifting array # <<   and do this too

    ./myProgram $ListOf256FilesNames  # << this works supposing the 2 lines before works
done

./myProgram $FILESTAB  # do the work for remaining files
```

Is there something like I want to do the job, or do you have any idea to do this using another way ?

Comment: See [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind). This discusses *properly* reading results into an array (the approach you're using above will fail badly with filenames with spaces, newline literals, expandable glob expressions, etc).

Comment: BTW, is there a reason you're doing batches of 256 at a time rather than letting `xargs` split your list into the largest-possible batch size that'll work?

Comment: Oh, tell me more about this (I don't know about this kind of thing using xargs)

Comment: BTW, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, with conventions on variable naming -- all-caps names are used by variables with meaning to the OS or shell, whereas the namespace with at least one lower-case character is guaranteed safe for applications to use without interfering with system behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your *real* goal is to avoid going over your operating system's maximum amount of allowed space for environment variables and arguments, you're better off letting `find` or `xargs` do that work for you. (This also avoids unintentionally going over when you get a bunch of unusually long filenames in a batch, or wasting CPU by running extra processes when you have really short names and could fit more).

---

#### Best Practice: Letting `find` Do The Division

Unlike `-exec ... {} ... \;`, which runs one command per filename, `-exec ... {} +` puts as many arguments onto each command line as possible. This is POSIX-compliant since 2007.

```
find /folder/where/the/files/are -name `*.xml` -exec ./myProgram '{}' +
```

#### Alternative: GNU `xargs`

Using `find -0` and `xargs -0` provides comparable functionality in a manner compatible with older tools:

```
find /folder/where/the/files/are -name `*.xml` -print0 | xargs -0 ./myProgram
```

If you *really* want to tell `xargs` to pass no more than 256 arguments to each invocation, you could make than `xargs -n 256 -0 ./myProgram`.

#### Suboptimally: Exactly What Was Requested

```
files=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  files+=( "$filename" )
done < <(find /folder/where/the/files/are/ -name '*.xml' -print0)

idx=0
while ((idx=0; idx<${#files[@]}; idx+=256)); do
  ./myProgram "${files[@]:$idx:256}"
done
```

Comment: Interesting find/exec option; For my problem in fact I have a first argument for my program (always the same, string type), this kind of thing will work you think: `find /folder/where/the/files/are -name \`*.xml\` -exec ./myProgram 'myFirstArgument {}' +` ?

Comment: The quoting's a bit wrong. `./myProgram 'myFirstArgument' {} +` is fine. `{}` needs to be its own argument, as does `+`.

Comment: You want to use the `-L`  option for xargs to limit to 256

Comment: @glennjackman, that's **if** the OP actually cares about the number 256. I believe it's been established that they don't; see comments on the question, particularly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571833/shell-script-for-each-element-in-array-256-by-256/45571987?noredirect=1#comment78103432_45571833 (in the context of the comment to which it's a reply).

Comment: @glennjackman @charles-duffy yeah true, 256 is not the real problem, I think I will rename the post (this number is due to the maximum command line arguments number allowed); `-n` allows to specify number of elements to get ?

Comment: @NathaëlNoguès, `-n` specifies the maximum number of elements to pass to each command -- so `xargs -n 1 myProgram` would pass only one argument to each instance of `myProgram`, `-n 2` would pass up to two, etc. Without `-n`, default behavior is just to squeeze on as many as possible (which is a dynamic number because it depends on the length of each string added as an argument, and on how much space is in use storing environment variables).